# How to locate and insert a value in a text box (input) using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, form-submit, html-input

I have the following HTML structure and I am trying to use Selenium to enter a value of `NUM`:

```
<div class="MY_HEADING_A">
    <div class="TitleA">My title</div>
    <div class="Foobar"></div>
        <div class="PageFrame" area="W">                
             <span class="PageText">PAGE <input id="a1" type="txt" NUM="" />  of <span id="MAX"></span> </span>
</div>
```

Here is the code I have written:

```
head = driver.find_element_by_class_name("MY_HEADING_A")
frame_elem = head.find_element_by_class_name("PageText")

# Following is a pseudo code. 
# Basically I need to enter a value of 1, 2, 3 etc in the textbox field (NUM) 
# and then hit RETURN key.
## txt  = frame_elem.find_element_by_name("NUM")
## txt.send_keys(Key.4)
```

How to get this element and enter a value‎‎‎‎‎‎‎? ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Assuming your page is available under "http://example.com"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://example.com")
```

Select element by id:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("a1")
inputElement.send_keys('1')
```

Now you can simulate hitting ENTER:

```
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

or if it is a form you can submit:

```
inputElement.submit()
```

Comment: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element

Comment: is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: You should wait for the element to be present prior to interaction. 
input_element = WebDriverWait(driver, WAIT_TIME).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#a1")))
input_element.send_keys("1")

Answer (score 1):

```
web=driver.get('your web address')
input_1=driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value= 'id of element')
input_2=driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value= 'id of element')
input_3=driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value= 'id of element')

time.sleep(7)
input_1.send_keys(your value)
input_2.send_keys(your value)
input_3.send_keys(your value)
```

Comment: I've reformatted your code, but please consider adding a description explaining why this is better than the accepted answer from 9 years ago. Is `by=By.ID` the new recommended usage? Has something changed in the API? Your answer will be a lot more valuable with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in 2023 you have to import By.

Make the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Replace `Input_you_want_to_send` and `THE_CLASS_OF_THE_ELEMENT` below with the names you are using.

```
Input_you_want_to_send = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'THE_CLASS_OF_THE_ELEMENT')
```

You may also use `by=` and `value=` as Rizwan Syal stated but this is optional now.

Sending the keys remain the same as of 2023.