# Replace placeholder text on a webpage using python and selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

The element where I want to replace text:

`<input tabindex="1" style="padding-left:119px!important;width:318px!important;background-color:#fff;outline: none;box-sizing: inherit;" id="email" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Number" class="un_s un1_s" value="" onblur="remove_border();" type="text" maxlength="20">`

I have tried various ways(all I could think up and google), to replace the `placeholder` text. Lots of errors later, I thought since the focus is already in the text box(where I want to enter the text may be just send_keys would work. It didn't. Can someone help me out and explain the concept or point to where I might read on where I went wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\-------\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("SAMPLE WEBSITE URL")  #sorry had to remove the link :(
driver.maximize_window()

action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
elm = driver.find_element_by_id("user_sign_in").click()

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lfm"]/div[1]/div[2]')     #driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Enter your Mobile Number')]")     
#driver.find_element_by_id("mobile")
inputElement.send_keys('1234567890')
inputElement.submit()


#//*[@id="lfm"]/div[1]/div[2] xpath id for the mobile number element
#code below this is not working, for move mouse
#action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
#action.move_to_element((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="user_sign_in"]')).perform()



#For moving the mouse to sign in: Tried the ones below and they didn't work either
#driver.move_to_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="user_sign_in"]')
#login_menu = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="user_sign_in"]')))
#ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(sign_in).perform()
```

Errors:

> > > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >           File "C:/Python34/Selenium 2nd Trial.py", line 16, in 
> > > >             inputElement.send_keys('9810307369')
> > > >           File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 322, in send_keys
> > > >             self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
> > > >           File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 457, in _execute
> > > >             return self._parent.execute(command, params)
> > > >           File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
> > > >             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> > > >           File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
> > > >             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> > > >         selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
> > > >           (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
> > > >           (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

Comment: How is your question different from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18557275/1426065)?

Comment: How does your current approach fail? Any errors?

Comment: @alecxe, updated with the errors, I was trying something else and forgot to change the find_elements to find_element as suggested by you earlier. MattDMo I tried to follow along with that answer but the send_keys approach is not working due to the updated error in the edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send keys to the `div` element, but meant to use an `input` element:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('email')   
inputElement.send_keys('1234567890')
inputElement.submit()
```

And, be aware that the page might take some time to load and there could be visual effects preventing an element to be located or interactable. If this is the case, use [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) with an appropriate Expected Condition to make sure element is visible.

Comment: This works perfectly. I have just started approaching the problem in a slightly different way after seeing this example. Since I am a beginner I am trying hit and trial on the elements from now on. :) Figured one out just now. Trying to learn each element as and when I make an error. Thanks for all your help. :)