# Input text into Input field in website with Python 3.6.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am trying to become good at programming with python. So I decided to create some sort of password cracker and try to crack a password of a site I've created.

I have already created the cracker, but now I need a way to output the text into a input box on a website.

Is there anyway to go to a site with python 3.6, check if there's a input box. Write something into the input box. Then press ENTER?

Comment: try using selenium

Comment: Check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557275/locating-entering-a-value-in-a-text-box-using-selenium-and-python

Comment: selenium doesn't work because I'm using python 3.6.0