# how to insert value in textbox using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am doing webscraping using selenium python but now i am facing problem in changing value in textbox,
I tried all the web elements but still i am not getting the way, so now I am trying to input textbox using set attribute function, so I just need help on syntax.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//* 
[@id='DLG_VARIABLE_vsc_cvl_VAR_55_INPUT_inp']").__setattr__('value','005/2020')
```

[HTML code from webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pKN8.jpg)

Comment: The basic docs of Selenium show exactly how to do this. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to locate and insert a value in a text box (input) using Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557275/how-to-locate-and-insert-a-value-in-a-text-box-input-using-python-selenium)

Comment: you are not able to find the element or you are not able , or it is not allowing you to change,, also what is the manual behavior gets modified or not