# How to fill an input and send it using python requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Im trying to use python requests to fill an input field and then send it using python requests.
Is it possible?

```
<div class="in">
    <span class="in-start"><i class="far fa-angle-right"></i></span>
    <input id="c-input" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: How about using selenium? like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557275/how-to-locate-and-insert-a-value-in-a-text-box-input-using-python-selenium

Comment: I have used Selenium and got it to work before. But I wanna just use requests to achieve it. I have searched all over the internet but mostly they talk about how to fill in forms for login

Comment: check the XHR and see if sent in POST. Then usually the data is passed within there as a parameter