# How do you locate and click on this button? Using python and selenium to web automate

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9A7R.png)

I'm having trouble clicking the Sign Up Now button which seems to be different than an input type button. It is also using ng-click and not sure how I can click on the button after multiple failed attempts.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: what have you tried?  Hint, use Find Element By Name.  It looks pretty simple

Comment: Could you provide more detailed code for reproduction so that we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try copiing the XPath and then using driver.find_element_by_xpath(*copied xpath*) function for locating the element and then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18558014/13219431) out - may help with clicking.

Comment: I was able to find a solution through the use of ActionChains and XPATH,
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(a).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", a)

Thank you for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

You can select it by name as JD2775 said, if you want to read a little more about it https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

you can try with

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_name('btnSignUp').click()
```

or

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_name('btnSignUp')
btn.click()
```

or something like that

Comment: I have just found a solution through an alternative method, I believe I did try finding it by name and it still wouldn't click. Thank you for the reply though!