# How do I go about scraping some data from chrome browser?

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, screen-scraping

The webpage I am trying to scrape can only be seen after login so using a direct url won't work. I need to scrape data while I am logged in using my chrome browser.
Then I need to get the value of the the element from

I have tried using the following code.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

lastdatadate=[]
lastprocesseddate=[]

source = requests.get('webpage.com').text
content = driver.page_source
soup = bs(content, 'lxml')
#print(soup.prettify())
price = soup.find('span', attrs={'id':'calculatedMinRate'})

print(price.text)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could still perform a login on the opened webdriver and fill in the input fields, as explained here: [How to locate and insert a value in a text box (input) using Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557275/how-to-locate-and-insert-a-value-in-a-text-box-input-using-python-selenium)

**Steps**:

1. Fill in the input fields
2. Find the submit button and trigger a click event
3. Afterwards add a sleep command, few seconds should be enough
4. Afterwards you should be able to get the data.